# Filter Ultragrid by Row state

Tags: vb.net, infragistics

**I have this code to filter my Ultragrid and it works fine**

```
Private Sub _txtAccountNum_TextChanged
(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles _txtAccountNum.TextChanged

        If sender.text = "" Then
            _MasterAccountBinding.Filter = ""
        End If
        If IsNumeric(sender.text) = True Then
            _MasterAccountBinding.Filter = "MainNum like '" & sender.text + "%'"
        Else
        End If
    End Sub
```

**But how to filter ultragrid by row state?  i want to filter(show only) updated/modified row**

Comment: I suppose that _MasterAccountBinding is a BindingSource, then you should show the code where the property DataSource of this variable is set. If it is a DataTable then you can filter the RowState there.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if Ultragrid supports this behavior - simply no experience using it. If it does not support filtering by row state, and your data source is a data table, you could create a DataView, using [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sd1cd0a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).